# Kivy app crashes when real ids used with kivmob

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer, kivymd

App works well when using testids but crashes when real ids are used

App code(Ads portion):
https://justpaste.it/9n5ks

Buildozer.spec:
https://justpaste.it/4835x

I already tried changing sdk versions but that didn't resolve the issue

Tried putting ad code to try-except too

Tried both debug and release modes of buildozer

Logcat:
https://justpaste.it/27n1z